# Custom controller which will search for a particular attribute in Magento v-1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, controllers

I have an issue currently where my `custom IndexController` performs a search correctly based on a product SKU.

However, once I try and edit the code to return results from a chosen attribute (In my case a product code). It doesn't function correctly.

Below is my SearchController:

```
public function searchAction(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $this->findProduct($id);

}

protected function loadNoRoute() {
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_NO_ROUTE_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
}

protected function findProduct($sku,$attributeSetId = null) {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('/product_url/'));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku',$sku);
    if ($attributeSetId) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId);
    }
    $collection->addUrlRewrite();
    $product = $collection->getFirstItem();
    $product['data'];
    // Check we have a product.
    if ($product->getId()) {
        // Get the URL and redirect to it.
        $url = $product->getProductUrl();
        // Parse URL
        $request = parse_url($url);
        $pageUrl = $request['path']; // Get URL without domain name
        if ($url) {
            $this->_redirectUrl('/support'.$pageUrl);
            return true;
        }

    }   // If we didn't find a matching product, load the default.
    $this->loadNoRoute();
    return false;
}
}
```

> It's really confusing me now why the Controller isn't outputting the results when the attribute $sku is swapped for $product_code as everything works as expected via the SKU search.

I'm obviously missing something here and wondered if somebody could help me or point me in the right direction.

I did previously have some help which fixed a separate problem and was a seriously good bit of code and advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `addAttributeToFilter` call, have you switched from *sku* to the respective attribute code?

Comment: I have switched everything from $sku to $product_code. The line had looked like this previously:

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('product_code',$product_code);

Comment: The code looks alright. Make sure your attribute code is correct and whether a correct value is being passed to $product_code variable.

Comment: Thanks @hungersoft for looking over it. I believe everything seems to be "sort of" working, it's literally the last step for my project. 

Is there an easy way to verify what is being passed? Currently it seems to just navigate to another random product page.

URL: https://mywebsiteurl/searchmodel/Search/search/?id=12345

Comment: You can do a simple echo $product_code; exit; to see the value being passed.

Comment: I have checked the value and it seems to pass through ok. Magento isn’t seeming to recognise the attribute and rewrite the URL to the product page. Like when the SKU is used.

Comment: I cannot think of anything other than the attribute code being wrong. You can also try doing a echo $collection->getSelect(); exit; and use the output query directly in your database server. Fix the query and try to fix the code accordingly. You can print the collection after each line in the code to find out which line stops returning the products.

Comment: Thank you, I will start with printing the collection and hopefully get a breakdown. I will then hopefully get more insight on it all. Thanks for your help.